# Random characters in stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm writing a program that searches for files. This block of code writes a folder name to a stringstream, preceding it with a "./" so that it can be used to change the directory. It then changes the directory and informs the user of the change.

```
stringstream maindir;
maindir << "./" << crntmainfile;
maindir.str().copy(maindirectory, 260, 0);
_chdir(maindirectory);
std::cout << maindirectory;
std::cout << "Main directory changed: " << maindirectory << "\n";
```

My problem is that `maindirectory` has a bunch of extra characters at the end. I'm assuming that this has to do with the fact that it's a 260 length array with maybe 20 characters in it and the extra characters are whatever happens to be occupying the unwritten memory. If this is my problem, how do I fix it?

EDIT:
I've determined that `crntmainfile` is null terminated, but the terminator is lost when it's written to `maindir`. What's causing this? Does `<<` simply not write null characters to stringstreams? How do I fix it?

EDIT:
I solved my problem by doing `maindir.put(0);` after `maindir << "./" << crntmainfile;` to manually null terminate the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string::copy` does not append a null character at the end of the copied content.

why don't you just do this

```
maindir << "./" << crntmainfile ;
maindir >> maindirectory;
maindir.clear();
```

Comment: Hmm... I changed 
    maindir << "./" << crntmainfile;
to
    maindir << "./" << crntmainfile << "\0";
but it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Apparently I can't have returns in comments. Sorry if that's hard to read.

Comment: if `crntmainfile` is a string, the extra null char is redundant. what exactly is not working

Comment: It isn't a string, it's a char*. _chdir can't change the directory properly with all of the extra characters in maindirectory.

Comment: look like `crntmainfile` is not null terminated, you need to make it so.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do that or will I need to write a function that figures out where to put it?

Comment: how was `crntmainfile` created

Comment: how exactly did you fill it. whatever you do, make sure you append '\0' after the last character.

Comment: That will be a bit of a problem. 
`std::wcstombs(crntmainfile, mainfiledata.cFileName, 260);`

Comment: Could I use `ZeroMemory()`?

Comment: use ur debugger to inspect the string and make sure they are null terminated, `wcstombs` will append null, so the problem may be `mainfiledata.cFileName`. Again, use the debugger.

Comment: It would seem that `crntmainfile` is null terminated, but the null terminator isn't being copied to `maindirectory`. I've tried inserting a `\0` into the stringstream, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @FlyingMonkey: Yeah, that's exactly what the docs say.  The only problem in your code is you don't check the return value of  `string.copy`, which tells you how many bytes were written to the array.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::copy` doesn't '\0' terminate the target, so you have to do this yourself.  A possibly better solution would be:

```
std::string mainDirectory( maindir.str() );
_chdir( mainDirectory.c_str() );
```

, and not use a `char[]` at all.

Comment: Some of the functions that I'm using only take chars as parameters, so I'm kind of stuck with them.

Comment: @FlyingMonkey For `char const*`, `mainDirectory.c_str()` is all you need.  For `char*`, it depends.  If it's legacy code, that doesn't actually change the data, then a `const_cast` on the return value of `mainDirectory.c_str()` is appropriate.  Otherwise, make sure that the `string` is big enough (using `resize`, _not_ `reserve`, and pass `&mainDirectory[0]`.